# Restricted firebase storage from editor and viewer access

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I have used firebase with my app. I am playing "owner" role here. There are some other user (with) like "Editor" & "Viewer" access. The viewer can view and the editor can view & edit firebase storage naturally.

But I want restrict only my storage part. They could not see and edit this part.

Is it possible?

Comment: done some spellcheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Firebase IAM roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles).  There is nothing specific to deny access for Cloud Storage, but you should look to see if there are other roles that you could grant to others who need access to certain products, without being able to change data in storage or databases.